# How to use revalidatePath in the nextjs client component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

```js
export const writePost = async (post: Post) => {
  const { content, title, writer, password } = post;
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/posts', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title,
      content,
      writer,
      password,
      createdDt: new Date().toISOString(),
      hits: 0,
    } as Post),
  });
  const data = (await res.json()) as Post;
  if (data.id) {
    revalidatePath('/') // Doesn't work.
    return { success: true };
  }
  return { success: false };
};

 const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { content, password, title, writer } = form;
    if (!content.value || !password.value || !title.value || !writer.value)
      return;
    const result = await writePost({
      content: content.value,
      title: title.value,
      writer: writer.value,
      password: password.value,
    });
    if (result.success) router.push('/');
  };
```

When you click a button in the client component, it sends a POST request to the server, like this

What I want is to stop caching when that request succeeds, like revalidatePath, and fetch the new posts from the server when it is moved to the path of "/" via useRouter.push, but it is fetching the old values. How can we get the new values?